# How to set manual update option in android app for the user?

Tags: java, android

I have developed an android application of a college. This application contain all the teachers and employee basic info such as photo, name, phone,email. I want to add an update button in this application. If the user press this update button the application will update. I will keep data for updating in a web server. when user press update option the app will take update data form that web server. For this, which way I can develop this application Can anyone help me? Please.

Comment: Can you be more precise ?

Comment: Hum, just display a list of the members and a button on top (or on the bottom) and when you click on the button, you just have to retrieve the data and update the list. I don't really understand what your question is..

Comment: This application already contain and display a list of the members and their basic info. Now If I want to update some info a member or add a new member I have to update the code and have to provide the new apk file to user. Now I want to add an update button in this application. After pressing this button the app will retrieve update or new data from a server through internet connection.

Answer (score 1):

you can use may be an [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to fetch the updated data, and in the onPostExecute method of Async Task, you can update all the views you need to update.

Comment: When he says "update the app", I think that he means "update the data of the app", such as a list, etc.